# Is it possible to generate a random number in python on a completely open interval or one that is closed on the high end?

Tags: python, random

I would like to generate a random number `n` such that `n` is in the range `(a,b)` or `(a,b]` where `a < b`. Is this possible in python? It seems the only choices are `a + random.random()*(b-a)` which is includes `[a,b)` or `random.uniform(a,b)` which includes the range `[a,b]` so neither meet my needs.

Comment: On the Reals, the probability that `r = a` is zero. If that is not sufficient, you could add an `epsilon` to `a + random.random()*(b-a)`

Comment: According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621055/random-in-python), the probability is not identically zero. It is a very small finite value. I suppose machine epsilon added to the output may be as close to `(a,b)` as possible. Any ideas on `(a,b]`?

Comment: Yes, I agree @AlexEshoo , that is because floats are not real.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Computer generation of "random" numbers is tricky, and especially of "random" floats.  You need to think long & hard about what you really want.  In the end, you'll need to build something on top of *integers*, not directly out of floats.

Under the covers, in Python (and every other language using the Mersenne Twister's source code), generating a "random" IEEE-754 double (Python's basic `random.random()`) really works by generating a random 53-bit integer, then dividing by 2**53:

```
randrange(2**53) / 9007199254740992.0
```

That's why the output range is `[0.0, 1.0)`, but not all representable floats in that range are equally likely.  Only the ones that can be expressed in the form `I/2**53` for an integer `0 <= I < 2**53`.  For example, the float `1.0 / 2**60` can never be returned.

There are no "real numbers" here, just representable binary-floating-point numbers, so to answer your question first requires that you specify the exact set of those from which you're trying to pick.

If the answer is that you don't want to get that picky, then the distinction between open and closed is also too picky to bother with.  If you *can* specify the precise set, then the solution is to generate more-or-less obvious random integers that map to your output set.

For example, if you want to pick "random" floats from [3.0, 6.0] with just 2 bits after the radix point, there are 13 possible outputs.  So the first step is

```
i = random.randrange(13)
```

Then map to the range of interest:

```
return 3.0 + i / 4.0
```

### EDIT: USELESS BUT EDUCATIONAL ;-)

As noted in the comments, picking uniformly from all representable floats `x` with `0.0 < x < 1.0` can be done, but is very far from being uniformly distributed *across* that range.  There are, for example, `2**52` representable floats in `[0.5, 1.0)`, but also `2**52` representable floats in `[0.25, 0.5)`, and ... in `[2.0**-i, 2.0**(1-i))` for increasing `i` until the number of representable floats starts shrinking when we hit the subnormal range, eventually falling to none when we underflow to 0 completely.

As bit patterns they're very simple, though:  the set of representable IEEE-754 doubles (Python floats on almost all platforms) in `(0, 1)` consists of, when viewing the bit patterns as integers, simply

```
range(1, 0x3ff0000000000000)
```

So a function to generate each of those with equal likelihood is straightforward to write using bit-fiddling tricks:

```
from struct import unpack
from random import randrange

def gen01():
    i = randrange(1, 0x3ff0000000000000)
    as_bytes = i.to_bytes(8, "big")
    return unpack(">d", as_bytes)[0]
```

Just run that a few times to see why it's useless - it's very heavily skewed toward the 0.0 end of the range:

```
>>> for i in range(10):
...     print(gen01())

9.796357610869274e-104
4.125848254595866e-197
1.8114434720880952e-253
1.4937625148849258e-285
1.0537573744489343e-304
2.79008159472542e-58
4.718459887295062e-217
2.7996009087703915e-295
3.4129442284798105e-170
2.299402306630583e-115
```

Comment: The exact set I would like to pick is all representable floats in the range `(0.0,1.0)` excluding the single value `0.0`

Comment: Are you sure of that?  For example, there are **far** more representable floats in `(0., 1/2**53)` than in `(1/2**53, 2/2**53)` - if you want them to all be equally likely, the results will be *very* heavily skewed toward 0, not at all a uniform distribution across `(0, 1)`.  Note that you also have to worry about denormalized floats.  You can write code for all that if you want, but it seems so useless and tedious to me you're not going to get me to write it for you ;-)

Comment: I suppose I will just deal with the very unlikely chance of getting zero (or just trying again if it is generated). In any case I did intend for this question to be more theoretical, and now I've got a lot more information about random floats so I'd say it succeeds there as well.

Comment: Glad it helped!  Note that `random.random()` has 1 chance in 2**53 of returning 0.0.  It _will_ return 0.0 if you try it often enough, but perhaps not in your lifetime ;-)  To be completely sure, yup, `while True: r = random(); if not r: break` is the standard "accept/reject" method to guarantee it.  But "guarantee" here is theoretical too - we're in the realm of things so rare that a spurious cosmic ray could flip a bit in your hardware and screw it all up anyway ;-)

Comment: BTW, note that `randrange(1, 2**53) / 9007199254740992.0` will do essentially the same as Python's `random.random()` but never return 0.0.

Comment: Then I shall also build a lead enclosure for my computer ;)

Answer (score 0):

`random.randint(a,b)` seems to do that. https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html

Comment: The docs say: `Return a random integer N such that a <= N <= b` which is `[a,b]` and not `(a,b]` or `(a,b)`

Answer (score 0):

Though a bit tricky, you may use [`np.random.rand`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html#numpy.random.rand) to generate random number in `(a, b]`:

```
import numpy as np

size = 10    # No. of random numbers to be generated
a, b = 0, 10    # Can be any values
rand_num = np.random.rand(size)    # [0, 1)
rand_num *= -1    # (-1, 0]
rand_num += 1    # (0, 1]
rand_num = a + rand_num * (b - a)    # (a, b]
```

Comment: Unfortunately this actually _can_ return `a`.  Set `a,b = 0, 5e-324`, and you'll see 0s in the output.  In a real situation this would never happen, of course, but this whole question is worrying about extremely unlikely edge cases. ;-)