# how to generate random numbers between closed interval [0,1]?

Tags: python-3.x, random

I need to get soma random values between closed interval [0,1] rather than opened interval. Is there any way this can be done?

Is this ok?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to generate a random number in python on a completely open interval or one that is closed on the high end?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107703/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-random-number-in-python-on-a-completely-open-interv)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

`random.uniform(0, 1)`

Note: When calling `N = random.uniform(a, b)`, the behaviour is always that `a <= N <= b` but the end-point value `b` may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding.

See https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=uniform#random.uniform

Answer (score 0):

First, try: `import random` `(random.randint(0,10**6)*1.0 /10**6)`
This will give you full floating point precision.
Otherwise, try:

import decimal

```
def randfloat():
    decimal.getcontext().prec = 10  # 10 decimal points enough?!
    return decimal.Decimal(0) + decimal.Decimal(random.uniform(0, 1))
# this should include both boundaries as float gets close enough to 1 to make decimal round

>>> decimal.Decimal(0) + decimal.Decimal(0.99999999999)
Decimal('1.000000000')
```

while uniform() apparently guarantees the inclusion of the lower boundary

Comment: More info: docs page: https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html?highlight=uniform#random.uniform  Clearly indicates that `a <= N <= b` but that the end-point value b may or may not be included in the range depending on floating-point rounding.