# What's the best way to generate uniformly random numbers on the open interval (0, 1) (so, not including the endpoints)?

Tags: python

What's the best way to generate uniformly random numbers on the open interval (0, 1) (so, not including the endpoints)? Is there a standard/reliable way that is recommended? My understanding is that neither `random.random` nor `random.uniform` are suitable for the open interval.

Comment: Is this link useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107703/is-it-possible-to-generate-a-random-number-in-python-on-a-completely-open-interv

Comment: @r.user.05apr Yes, it is. I guess the answer is "it isn't possible," but I wonder whether I should keep this open and link to that question as a duplicate, since it seems that my question would be easier for people to find.